# iOS 9, Swift 2.0: Retrieving a Dictionary from JSON file

Tags: ios, json, swift, cocoa-touch

I am trying to get access to a dictionary that is inside a JSON file. This is my first time trying to read a JSON file. I'm looking for a way to return the result of getImageId, however my variable imageID doesn't get changed to the value returned by self.getImageId(keyWord, jsonDictionary: jsonDictionary!)! and stays as nil.

```
func getEmotes(keyWord: String)-> NSNumber{
    //Returns NSURL?.  nil if the url is not valid
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    var imageID: NSNumber? = nil
    //Response: HHTP response, NSData the data contained in the file, NSError no internet, etc.
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) in
        if error == nil{
            //To get URL response.
            let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse

            if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                var jsonDictionary: NSDictionary? = nil

                do {
                    jsonDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                }catch{ }

                if jsonDictionary != nil{
                    //The retrieval Dictionary inside Json was sucesful.
                    //NEED: Return the value from this:
                    imageID = self.getImageId(keyWord, jsonDictionary: jsonDictionary!)!
                }
            }else{
                print(httpResponse.statusCode)
            }
        }

    }
    print(imageID)
    return imageID ?? 0
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You will never get something else than 0 as return value because *send**Asynchronous**Request* implies to work asynchronously that means the response is returned much later in the completion block after the function exits.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a return block.
I did not add any error handling to the return block, you will need to add it.

```
getEmotes("keyword") { (imageID) in
    print(imageID)
}

func getEmotes(keyWord: String, returnBlock: (imageID: NSNumber?) -> Void)-> Void{
//Returns NSURL?.  nil if the url is not valid
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
var imageID: NSNumber? = nil
//Response: HHTP response, NSData the data contained in the file, NSError no internet, etc.
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) in
    if error == nil{
        //To get URL response.
        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse

        if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
            var jsonDictionary: NSDictionary? = nil

            do {
                jsonDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            }catch{ }

            if jsonDictionary != nil{
                //The retrieval Dictionary inside Json was sucesful.
                //NEED: Return the value from this:
                imageID = self.getImageId(keyWord, jsonDictionary: jsonDictionary!)!
                returnBlock(imageID: imageID)
            }
        }else{
            print(httpResponse.statusCode)
        }
    }

}
```

}